# Material Calendar View Height wrapping issue

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am using [material calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) which blocks 3/4 of screen height. I customized screen height but still it have some padding between day tiles and height of calendarview.

Below i attached a screenshot how is looking now:

[image]

Comment: show us your code

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView.java

Replaced tileheight by this line 
            int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    p.height * (int) (measureTileHeight / 1.5),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found, after the long time effort work on libs at `onMeasure()` method.

```
measuredHeight = (int)(measuredHeight/1.5);
setMeasuredDimension(
            //We clamp inline because we want to use un-clamped versions on the children
            clampSize(measuredWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            clampSize(measuredHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
```

Comment: Hello sir can you please help me out i am also facing the same problem can you let me know where exactly i have to put this code snipet

Comment: i am using this library as a module and customizing according to our flow